# How to hide pythontex commands in the output?

Tags: pythontex

The following code I am running in Cocalc. It is in a latex document with pythontex.

[image: Latex Code]

The output looks like this.

[image: Output of Latex Code]

I would like to not show the input code which I highlighted in a pink box on the second picture. How do I hide the code and show only the mathematical result. My goal is to be able to have a presentation ready document where I can choose to show the code if I want to. I tried \hphantom{}, \begin{comment} to hide this code but then my output for z shows "z=??". Maybe I am using them wrong. I am very new latex.

Answer (score 1):

The environments defined by PythonTeX come in at least three flavors:

- `...code` runs but does not typeset.
- `...block` runs and typesets.
- `...verbatim` typesets but does not run.

So you should change `sympyblock` to `sympycode` if you don't want to show the code.

For future reference, PythonTeX has very extensive reference. Reading [the documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/pythontex?lang=en) would absolutely help for questions like this.